# Ubuntu, I need to access a standard users files within a admin account, terminal or other method is fine

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, filesystems

I have a file I would like to retrieve from a standard account I can’t log into. Basically from admin account I need to type some commands in terminal or go threw files app to access the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after some deep research here is the answer to my own question. With being able to log in as Admin here are the steps. 1. Log in to admin account 2. Open terminal 3. Type ‘sudo nautilus’ & then enter password 4. Travel to ‘other locations’ 5. Click on ‘ computer’ 6. Click on ‘home’ folder 7. Click on user who’s files you want to access and wa-la.